# Convert eBay SOAP response to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, ebay-api

I have eBay notification set up and i want to convert the notification content (which is SOAP XML) to GetItemTransactionsResponse Java Object. Below is the code i am using.

```
SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(
                           CONVERT_EBAY_NOTIFICATION_TO_BYTE_ARRAY_METHOD()
                    ));
SOAPEnvelope soapEnv = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPBody soapBody = message.getSOAPBody();
JAXBContext content = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetItemTransactionsResponseType.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = content.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBIntrospector jaxbIntrospector = content.createJAXBIntrospector();
Object transactionObject = unmarshaller.unmarshal(soapBody, GetItemTransactionsResponseType.class);
GetItemTransactionsResponseType transaction = (GetItemTransactionsResponseType)jaxbIntrospector.getValue(transactionObject);
```

I thought this would convert the SOAP XML to the corresponding eBay Object, but it doesn't work because the "transaction" object is null... I tried to access the variable in "transaction" object

```
transaction.getItem()
```

and i receive NullPointerException...

then I check my soapBody object to see if I am passing in empty content that causes the NullPointerException

```
soapBody.getTextContent()
```

I can see text contents inside the soapBody object. It is not empty!

I would really appreciate any help that could solve this problem. Not sure if I am converting the SOAP XML incorrectly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well somehow I managed to figured out the problem.

I actually need to obtain the body part of the SOAP XML using Document:

```
Document document = soapBody.extractContentAsDocument();
```

Then I unmarshall the Document object instead of the SOAPBody object, into Object:

```
Object transactionObject = unmarshaller.unmarshal(document);
```

Lastly I use JAXBIntrospector to get the object value and also cast the object to GetItemTransactionsResponseType class like what i did originally:

```
GetItemTransactionsResponseType transaction = (GetItemTransactionsResponseType)jaxbIntrospector.getValue(transactionObject);
```

I am going to leave the code here to hopefully help someone who is struggling like i did.

```
SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_IMPLEMENTATION_TO_GET_YOUR_SOURCE()
                    ));
SOAPBody soapBody = message.getSOAPBody();
Document document = soapBody.extractContentAsDocument();
JAXBContext content = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetItemTransactionsResponseType.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = content.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBIntrospector jaxbIntrospector = content.createJAXBIntrospector();
Object transactionObject = unmarshaller.unmarshal(document);            
GetItemTransactionsResponseType transaction = (GetItemTransactionsResponseType)jaxbIntrospector.getValue(transactionObject);
```